# How can I wrap another type and add fields and methods to it?

Tags: vector, rust

I know inheritance is a bad word in the Rust world, however there must be some way, given the following struct

```
struct Glyph {
    // Fields
}
```

to have a new `Glyphs` struct that is a wrapper for `Vec<Glyph>` methods (`push`, etc.) as well as fields and methods proper to itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a type alias (i.e. a synonym):

```
type Glyphs = Vec<Glyph>;
```

It is not a distinct type, so you can pass a `Glyphs` to any function that expects a compatible `Vec`, including generic functions.

You will not be able to add fields or inherent methods to this type directly. What you can do, though, is define an extension trait (i.e. a trait that exists for the sole purpose of adding methods to a type you didn't define; there's no special syntax for this) and have `Glyphs` implement it. If you use modules, you'll have to import the trait with `use` to bring the methods into scope.

```
trait GlyphsExt {
    fn x(&self); // define extension method
}

impl GlyphsExt for Glyphs {
    fn x(&self) {
        // implement method here
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question as posed, unfortunately: *as well as **fields** and methods proper to itself*.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Deref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html), like so:

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

struct Glyph;

struct Glyphs(Vec<Glyph>);

impl Glyphs {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Glyphs(vec![])
    }
}

impl Deref for Glyphs {
    type Target = Vec<Glyph>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Vec<Glyph> { &self.0 }
}

impl DerefMut for Glyphs {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Glyph> { &mut self.0 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut gs = Glyphs::new();
    gs.push(Glyph);
    gs.push(Glyph);
    println!("gs.len: {}", gs.len());
}
```

Note that this *is not* inheritance.  A big limitation is that you absolutely cannot prevent someone from calling any of `Vec`'s methods, since they can just manually deref a `Glyphs` into a `Vec<Glyph>`.  You can "override" methods by defining them on `Glyphs`, but again, someone can just go behind your back by manually dereferencing a `Glyphs`.

You may also wish to read the [`Deref` coercions chapter of the Rust Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you shouldn't use Deref and DerefMut to emulate some aspects of inheritance. They exist for writing custom pointer types.

When you're writing a wrapper struct like this, you typically only need some of `Vec`s functionality. There may also be some invariants that need to hold. By implementing `Deref` and `DerefMut` you're making your `Glyphs` harder to reason about and easier to misuse. Avoiding to expose implementation details is generally also preferable.

So the solution would be to implement the functions you need on `Glyphs`. These are probably only a few. And if you really need all or most of `Vec`s functions and trait implementations, then a wrapper struct wasn't the right choice to begin with.